# Generic Being Ignored in Java

Tags: java, generics

So I have this Java code:

```
public <A extends Action> List<A> getActionsFor(Actor a) {
    List<A> theActions = super.getActionsFor(a);

    for (Action ac: a.getItemCarried().getActions()) {
        theActions.add(ac);
    }

    return theActions;
}
```

For some reason javac is rejecting the .add(ac) claiming add(A) cannot be applied to Action.

Am I missing something key here? I can work around this by creating dependencies across two packages but I really do not want to do that.

All classes in question have been imported correctly, and each method called works, so I am really lost as to why it can't accept the class type that A extends.

Any suggestions even if you aren't sure would be appreciated as I have to get this fixed within the next 6 hours, otherwise I'll need to create that dependency.

Comment: So, how do I make it accept 'Action' then?
'A' should already take anything of type 'Action' or that extends from 'Action' shouldn't it?

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer and expanded upon it

Comment: One thing to add: generic types don't have the same kind of super/subclass relationships that you might expect. For example, an `ArrayList<Number>` is **not** a supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>`. Why? If `ArrayList<Number>` were a supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>`, you could do `ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, which would then let you put `Number` objects into `list`, which is supposed to be an `ArrayList<Integer`! Thus, when you have a `List<A extends Action>`, you can't add `Actions` to it because `List<Action>` is not a supertype of `List<A extends Action>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something key here?

`A` is something which extends Action,  `ac` is also something which extends Action.  However this is a bit like the facility

```
Yesterday I saw someone.
Someone is the President
Therefor, yesterday I was the President.
```

The problem is the compiler has no may of knowing that the `A` and the `Action` are compatible sub-classes of `Action`

A simple work around is to not be so specific. Use `Action` instead of `A` in this method.

```
public List<Action> getActionsFor(Actor a) {
    // this has to return a copy of the List or you will be modifying an original
    List<Action> theActions = super.getActionsFor(a);

    for (Action ac: a.getItemCarried().getActions()) {
        theActions.add(ac); // ac is an Action so all good.
    }

    return theActions;
}
```

OR you could do what you had, but more complicated

```
public <A extends Action> List<A> getActionsFor(Actor<A> a) {
    List<A> theActions = super.getActionsFor(a);

    for (A ac: a.getItemCarried().getActions()) {
        theActions.add(ac); // ac is an A, so all good.
    }

    return theActions;
}
```

Comment: The second solution you provided returns the exact same error, but the the first solution did work. It really confuses me because almost identical code exists in the super class referencing different classes but with the same relationships, and it works fine there.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: @David The second approach will only work if `getActions()` return a `List<A>` note: the `Actor<A>`  There is much more changes to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an explicit list of `A`, if you want to accept all subclasses, specify so in your list declaration:

```
List<? extends A> theActions = super.getActionsFor(a);
```

Comment: This won't let you add(), only get()

Comment: Ah yes, you are right about that. In that case I would say your answer is more correct for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<A extends Action>` as generic type you cannot add elements to a `List` typed with `A` in a typesafe way.

The reason for this is that you don't know the exact type of `A`.

Lets assume you have two subclasses of `Action`: `ActionA` and `ActionB`.

Now it is perfectly valid to write this:

```
List<A> theActions = new ArrayList<ActionA>();
```

But now you can't add any object to `theActions` because the type of `theActions` (`<A extends Action>`) does not tell you if it is a List of `Action`, `ActionA` or `ActionB`. Therefore you can't add anything to `theActions`:

```
theActions.add(new Action()); // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have not specified what is the `A` that is a subclass of `Action`. You want to add an instance of a supertype of `A` (an `Action`), that is not allowed. You need to cast to `A` (not safe, gives warning), or return just `List<Action>`.